# Integration of weak $L^p$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I want an accurate understanding of weak norm.

The definition of weak $L^p$:
$$ \left\lVert f \right\rVert_{p,\infty}=\sup_{a>0} a \mu \{|f|>a\}^{1/p}.  $$

The question is:

> Let $v$: velocity, $x$: location in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $t$: time variable, $E(t, x) : \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.
>
> 1. Show that
>    $$\left\lVert E(t,x-s\cdot) \right\rVert_{\frac{3}{2},\infty}=s^{-2} \left\lVert E(t,\cdot) \right\rVert_{\frac{3}{2},\infty} $$
>    (In this problem, how to change of variable without integration? Can I use Jacobian?)

Answer (score 0):

$$ \{y : sy-x \in A \} = \tfrac1s (A+x) $$ and $$\mu\left(\tfrac1s (A+x)\right) = \tfrac1{s^3} \mu(A) .$$
Now let $$A = \{|E(t,\cdot)| > a\}.$$